# Can't set cell width using docx4j

Tags: java, doc, docx4j

How to set width for cell? I tried trough cell properties, but it does not work

```
private void addTableCell(Tr tableRow, String content, boolean setWidth, int width) {
    Tc tableCell = factory.createTc();

    if (setWidth) {
        setCellWidth(tableCell, width);
    }

    tableCell.getContent().add(
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().
                    createParagraphOfText(content));
    tableRow.getContent().add(tableCell);
}

private void setCellWidth(Tc tableCell, int width) {
    TcPr tableCellProperties = new TcPr();
    TblWidth tableWidth = new TblWidth();
    tableWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
    tableCellProperties.setTcW(tableWidth);
    tableCell.setTcPr(tableCellProperties);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also set w:tbl/w:tblGrid; see further [ecma376/WordML/Tables](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/Tables.html)

The easiest way to set things appropriately is to make a table to your liking in Word, then generate corresponding code from that using the docx4j webapp, or the Docx4jHelper Word AddIn.

For more on w:tcW, see [the spec](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/tcW.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you need to set the width type for the cell.  Try adding

tableWidth.setType("dxa");

before calling setTcW() in your setCellWidth function.